# Set-Cookie with Google HTTP Client Library for Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-http-client

I just started using the [Google HTTP Client Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/) and I like it a lot.  However, I don't know if there's an easy way to handle the case when a server sends header Set-Cookie.  I looked through documentation, sample code, and Javadoc and saw nothing, so I started implementing my own solution.  However, this process seems common enough that I would think Google would have implemented a solution for everyone.

Server sends something like:

```
Set-Cookie: uid=ef308bd9-4580-4ef0-8cdd-2b09f383419e; Expires=Tue, 31 Dec 2199 23:59:59 GMT; Domain=mydomain.com; Path=/
```

My client has to manually parse it all:

```
String[] parts = cookie.split(";");
if (parts.length > 0) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\\s=]*)=(.*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(parts[0]);
    if (m.matches()) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(m.group(1), m.group(2));
        if (parts.length > 1) {
            for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                // parse and set "Expires", "Max-Age", "Domain", "Path",
                // "Secure", "HttpOnly", etc.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any library method to handle this stuff instead of me implementing it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To parse cookies use

```
java.net.HttpCookie.parse(String header)
```

Still need to store parsed cookies and send them with Cookie header. There are plenty solutions for cookie handling over internet though it's odd that Google doesn't provide it with their library.

Comment: Great!  I didn't know about net.java.HttpCookie.  Now, after using that static method to parse it, I still need to translate it to a javax.servlet.http.Cookie, but that's pretty straight forward using getter and setters.  The one complication was the incompatibility between HttpCookies's maxAge long and Cookie's maxAge int.

Comment: When you pass in header, where does that come from? Do you still need to do string munging or is there some easy way to get the value of set-cookie from googles httpclient without it outputting an array?